# How to count click/view of my WordPress site videos?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I use Video Gallery Plugin for my WordPress site and show videos on my website videos page. I want something like Kama Click counter (check & counts clicks on the specific link) that shows me the number of click on the specific video. Is there any plugin to count the click on videos?

Any suggestion, please?

Advance Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try wp power stats by igor buyanov, wp statistics
by verona labs, visitors traffic real time statistics
by wp-buy personally i don't use those plugin but i hear both plugin do a good job when its about stasticks.